# NSPredicate not working for string that contains "&"

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate

The following is the filter format I set in my `NSPredicate`.

```
  NSString *filter;
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@",filter];
```

This code works fine except when the 'filter' string contains an '&'.

Example :

`filter = @"Ron";` returns an array of objects that contain 'Ron' during `performFetch` .

But `filter = @"Johnson & Johnson"` returns an empty array even though an object in CoreData contains the exact same name.
Same happens for any other string that contains an '&'.

What is the proper format to specify special characters in NSPredicate?

Comment: Try to escape special characters to isolate the root of the issue. Like `@"Johnson \\& Johnson"`.